# How to open system notification categories screen in Samsung devices programmatically

Tags: android, notifications, samsung-mobile, system-setting

I am using the snip code below to open the system notification categories screen:

```
Intent settingsIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_APP_NOTIFICATION_SETTINGS)
       .putExtra(Settings.EXTRA_APP_PACKAGE, getPackageName());

startActivity(settingsIntent);
```

It works fine on almost every device. It will open this screen:

[Expectation screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctAGX.jpg)

But in Samsung devices, the following activity was shown instead:

[Samsung device screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ci0p5.jpg)

So, how do I open the notification categories screen on Samsung devices?